# Why is my viewModel empty when using sharedViewModel method in Jetpack Compose navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm making a notes app that passes two strings (Title and Content) from a home screen to an update screen so user can update them. There's a notes screen that creates a new note and saves in a room database and displays in a lazyColumn on the home screen. I tried passing the Title and Content strings using the arguments method in jetpack compose navigation and it worked but I'm trying to use the sharedViewModel method and the viewModel is empty for some reason. And i'm using hilt to provide dependencies.

The update screen is retrieving an empty list from the viewModel hence crashes the app. i can't seem to figure out what the problem is

Home Screen

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    notes: List<Note>,
    navController: NavController,
    onNavigate: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: NotesViewModel
){


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        LazyColumn{
            items(notes.size){ index ->
                val note = notes[index]
                NoteItem(
                    note = note,
                    onDeleteIconClick = {
                        viewModel.deleteNote(note)
                    },
                    onItemClick = onNavigate
                )
            }
        }

        FloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.NoteScreen.route)
            },
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_add_24),
                contentDescription = "Add Button"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Navigation System

```
@Composable
fun Navigation(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "route1"){
        navigation(
            startDestination = Screen.HomeScreen.route,
            route = "route1"
        ){
            composable(Screen.HomeScreen.route){ entry ->
                val viewModel = entry.notesViewModel<NotesViewModel>(navController = navController )
                val state by viewModel.getAllNotes.collectAsState(initial = listOf())

                HomeScreen(
                    notes = state,
                    navController = navController,
                    onNavigate = {
                                 navController.navigate(Screen.UpdateScreen.route)
                    },
                    viewModel = viewModel
                )
            }
            composable(Screen.UpdateScreen.route){ entry ->
                val viewModel = entry.notesViewModel<NotesViewModel>(navController = navController )
                val state by viewModel.getAllNotes.collectAsState(initial = listOf())

                UpdateScreen(
                    notes = state,
                    navController = navController, 
                    viewModel = viewModel
                )
            }
            composable(Screen.NoteScreen.route){ entry ->
                val viewModel = entry.notesViewModel<NotesViewModel>(navController = navController )
                NoteScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                    viewModel = viewModel
                )
            }
        }

    }


}
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.notesViewModel(
    navController: NavController,
): T {
    val navGraphRoute =destination.parent?.route ?: return hiltViewModel()
    val parentEntry = remember(this){
        navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
    }
    return hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
}
```

Note Screen

```
@Composable
fun NoteScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: NotesViewModel
){

    var textFieldNoteTitle by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var textFieldNoteContent by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(0.8f)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                value = textFieldNoteTitle,
                onValueChange = {changedValue ->
                    textFieldNoteTitle = changedValue
                },
                label = {
                    Text(text = "Title")
                }
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(8f)
        ){
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                value = textFieldNoteContent,
                onValueChange = {changedValue ->
                    textFieldNoteContent = changedValue
                },
                label = {
                    Text(text = "Content")
                },
                maxLines = Int.MAX_VALUE
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(0.5f)

        ){
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
                onClick = {
                    textFieldNoteTitle.let { title ->
                        Note(0, title, textFieldNoteContent).let {
                            viewModel.addNote(it)
                        }
                    }
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            ) {
               Text(
                   text = "Add",
                   color = Color.White
               )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Update Screen

```
@Composable
fun UpdateScreen(
    notes: List<Note>,
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: NotesViewModel
){
    val currentItemIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    var textFieldNoteTitle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(notes[currentItemIndex].noteTitle)
    }

    var textFieldNoteContent by remember {
        mutableStateOf(notes[currentItemIndex].noteContent)
    }

    val noteIdState = rememberSaveable{
        mutableStateOf(notes[currentItemIndex].id)
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(0.8f)
        ) {
            textFieldNoteTitle?.let {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = it,
                    onValueChange = {changedValue ->
                        textFieldNoteTitle = changedValue
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = "Title")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(8f)
        ){
            textFieldNoteContent?.let {
                TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                    value = it,
                    onValueChange = {changedValue ->
                        textFieldNoteContent = changedValue
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = "Content")
                    },
                    maxLines = Int.MAX_VALUE,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(0.5f)

        ){
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
                onClick = {
                    textFieldNoteTitle?.let { title ->
                        textFieldNoteContent?.let { content ->
                            Note(noteIdState.value, title, content)
                        }?.let {
                            viewModel.updateNote(it)
                        }
                    }
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Update",
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Notes ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val noteRepository: NoteRepository
): ViewModel() {
    val getAllNotes: Flow<List<Note>> = noteRepository.getAllNotes()

    fun addNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        noteRepository.addNote(note)
    }

    fun updateNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        noteRepository.updateNote(note)
    }

    fun deleteNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        noteRepository.deleteNote(note)
    }
}
```

Routes

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String){
    object HomeScreen: Screen("home_screen")
    object NoteScreen: Screen("note_screen")
    object UpdateScreen: Screen("update_screen")
}
```